# BTreeMap of f64's

Tags: rust

I would like to have a sorted array which has an f64 as key and an f64 as value.
I need to update, delete and insert to this array by finding the right key.
I need to get the first 1000 sorted entries, and also the first entry.
These operations must be fast.

By reading [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/index.html), I thought BTreeMap is good for me.

However, when I try to insert into it I got this error message:

```
the trait bound `f64: Ord` is not satisfied
the trait `Ord` is not implemented for `f64`rustcE0277
```

What is the recommended way to do this with Rust?

My code:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

pub struct MyStruct {
  pub map: BTreeMap<f64, f64>
}

impl MyStruct {
  pub fn new() -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct {
      map: BTreeMap::new()
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_struct = MyStruct::new();
    my_struct.map.insert(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not good candidates for keys. Maybe you should consider converting them to integers or strings. For example, if you only care about 2 digits after the decimal separator, you can do something like n*100, rounded and converted to an integer type.

Comment: Maybe you can explain why they're not a good choice for keys (lack of `Ord`, rounding in arithmetic operations, etc.)?

Answer (score 7):

I think you may be looking for the [`ordered_float`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/index.html) crate and either the [`OrderedFloat`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/struct.OrderedFloat.html) (can store NaN, sorts it above `+inf`) or [`NotNan`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/struct.NotNan.html) (cannot store NaN) structs, which both are a float-like type that is `Eq` and `Ord` (in violation of the IEEE standard).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nutype](https://github.com/greyblake/nutype) crate.

With nutype you can add `finite` validation on your newtype, which excludes `NaN` and `Infinity`.
This allows to derive `Eq` and `Ord`:

```rs
use nutype::nutype;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[nutype(
    validate(finite),
    derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord),
)]
pub struct Float(f64);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
  pub map: BTreeMap<Float, Float>
}

impl MyStruct {
  pub fn new() -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct {
      map: BTreeMap::new()
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_struct = MyStruct::new();
    let one = Float::new(1.0).unwrap();
    let two = Float::new(2.0).unwrap();
    my_struct.map.insert(one, two);

    println!("{my_struct:?}");
}
```

Output:

```
MyStruct { map: {Float(1.0): Float(2.0)} }
```